# Why isn't there a \$\small\sqrt 3\$ factor between rated currents on the delta-wye transformer?

Tags: current, transformer, y-to-delta

When calculating the rated current on either side of a delta-wye transformer, we will use the following equation:

$$
I_{LL}= \dfrac{S_{3\Phi}}{\sqrt 3\cdot V_{LL}}
$$

Since this same equation is used for either the delta and the wye side, there is no \$\small\sqrt 3\$ factor between these two currents. For example, if the high side is 66 kV and the low side is 12 kV, then for a 28 MVA transformer, the rated currents on each side will be:

$$
I_{LL}= \dfrac{28\ \text{MVA}}{\sqrt3\cdot 66\ \text{kV}} = 245\ \text{A}
$$

$$
I_{LL}= \dfrac{28\ \text{MVA}}{\sqrt3\cdot 12\ \text{kV}} = 1347\ \text{A}
$$

So according to this equation, the only factor between the line to line currents of the low and the high side is the transformer ratio, which happens to be 5.5 in this example. My question is, why isn't \$\small\sqrt 3\$ also a factor?

For example, if we were to find the rated current of the high side to be 245 A, then shouldn't the rated current on the low side be given by:

$$
I_{LL}= \sqrt 3\cdot Transformer\_ratio\cdot 245 = 2334\ \text{A}
$$

Why do we ignore the \$\small\sqrt 3\$ factor between the high and the low side of a delta-wye transformer when calculating rated currents?

Comment: Didn't you already answer this yourself? "Since this same equation is used for either the delta and the wye side, there is no square root of 3 factor between these two currents."

Comment: No, I did not explain why it's acceptable to use this equation and ignore the square root of 3 relationship between the delta and the wye side. But if you know a reason besides "because we use this equation instead of the other", please feel free to share.

Answer (score 1):

The root of 3 factor applies when you switch the **same** windings from delta to wye and back.

But your transformer is already designed to have primary delta and secondary wye windings. So its rated voltages and currents already account for any wye/delta conversion. For example, every phase of its delta winding has square root of 3 times higher rated current than it would be, if the same winding would  be connect in wye configuration.

If you don't build, but just use the tranformer, then you don't even have to know how windings are connected inside to calculated "outer" rated currents.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of 3 factor has to do with the voltage relation between the 3 phases and neutral, which normally is consistent. That they are 120 degrees out of phase is a moot point. Current depends on the load and is not always a balanced load.

Since the load is unknown, dynamic and maybe unbalanced it cannot be used as a reference for static equations such as the square root of 3.

This assumes all 3 phases are sampled at the same time, so there is no artificial add-on delay in current readings.

Comment: I found out the actual reason and posted an answer. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I found out why, and it's very simple. We do this calculation for relay settings. But it so happens that microprocessor relays are the ones to do the calculation for the phase shift (magnitude and angle), so there is no need for us to calculate the phase shift manually.

Comment: Should that be 'delay, not 'relay'?

Comment: In such a case the delay of the CPU would have to be known, including switching delay. If all 3 phases are sampled at the same time there is no delay.

Comment: There is no typo. I am not sure why you guys are insisting on the word "delay", when I am talking about a relay. Microprocessor relays are widely used in power systems to detect faults.

Comment: For an electromechanical relay, it was typical to compensate for magnitude and phase by connecting CT's in delta and using CT ratios like 100/0.577 amps (0.577 = 1/sqrt(3)). Connecting the CT's in delta was also required to reject zero sequence currents from the relay. Nowadays this is all done in software.